# How to get notifications when xtext's EMF model changes with proper values

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, xtext, eclipse-emf, emf

We have a FormEditor containing four pages: three FormPages and fourth page is XTextEditor as a source page.

Whenever user makes any changes (e.g. changing value in text box) on FormPages, we change EMF model content inside XTextDocument.modify() method as given below:

```
    xtextEditor.getDocument().modify(new IUnitOfWork.Void<XtextResource>() {

        @Override
        public void process(XtextResource state) throws Exception {
            IParseResult parseResult = state.getParseResult();
            Assert.isNotNull(parseResult);
            EObject rootASTElement = parseResult.getRootASTElement();

            if (rootASTElement instanceof MyModel) {
               XyzType t = ((MyModel) rootASTElement).getXyzType();
                t.setName(name);   <- ‘name’ is the new value entered on FormPage text box
            }
        }
    });
```

Now, we want to get notifications in FormPages, whenever EMF model gets changed when user makes some changes on source page i.e. XTextEditor.

We tried adding IXtextModelListener and IXtextDocumentContentObserver to IXtextDocument; but these get called for every character entered in XTextEditor.

Our requirement is to get notifications only when values in EMF model get changed (and not for text formatting e.g. when whitespace is inserted/removed).

Can somebody please provide some pointers?

Regards,
Akhil

Comment: did you also try to build upon `org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.Notifier`?

Comment: @SpaceTrucker: Thanks for your quick reply!! I didn't use this approach. Can you please tell me about it in detail?

Comment: I haven't used that API myself, but since every `EObject` implements it, I thought suggesting it would be a good idea. You would have to register the same `org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.Adapter` to every object in your model. This adapter will get notified when your model changes. But in order for this to work, the xtext editor must not create a new model every time, but has to modify the existing one.

Comment: Did you found a solution of your question?

Comment: since xtext does recreated the emf model all the time the listeners wont help. you would have to keep copies of the model all the time and compare the copy with the current state of the model all the time to find out if something actually changed

Answer (score 0):

You can use the EMF Client Platform (ECP), which adds an implementation of an [Observer Bus to an EMF model](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/tutorials/emf-client-platform-core-api/#observerbus).

They implement an own validation service which does what you described:

> [ecp.view.validation](http://www.eclipse.org/ecp/documentation.html)
>   This is the validation service, which monitors the domain model and 
>   calculates validation errors.

The validation service already uses the Observer Bus of ECP to register to EMF change events. The Observer Bus itself is implemented as an EContentAdapter listening to every change of the model. It already filters the change events and provides them following the Observer Bus pattern to the event bus which you can register. There you only get the events you registered to and not all events as for the EContentAdapter which you have to filter for yourself.

I think they mainly use it to validate models to show results in their EMF Forms GUI. However, you can use the services also standalone.